# How to use \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}?

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

Could anyone tell me how to use `\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}`? Here is the website of package,

```
 http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/
```

When I run PDFTeXify, there always show some font that can not be found. How to solve this problem? Please help me and illustrate detailed steps.

Here is the error information:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file EBGaramond12-Italic--oml-ebgaramond):
>
> Font EB Garamond12-Italic--oml-ebgaramond at 500 not found
>
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file).

Please help me.

Comment: How do you load the packages? (I would try `\usepackage{ebgaramond,ebgaramond-maths}`.) Which TeX distribution, and which vintage, do you employ? The reason I ask is that the `ebgaramond-maths` package is of fairly recent vintage. If you have an older TeX distribution, the package may not be installed (or installed fully).

Comment: As the compiler tries to make bitmap fonts, it looks like `dvips.pdflatex` are not aware of the type 1 fonts. You should run `updmap` or `initexmf -mkmaps`.

Comment: @Mico You don't need to load `ebgaramond` separately as `ebgaramond-maths` loads it anyway. It looks as if the package is not installed properly. Current TeX Live certainly includes it. (In any case, if you are using TeX Live, do ***not*** run `updmap` ever if you can help it. Use `updmap-sys` if necessary.) Guessing this is a MiKTeX install, though, since MiKTeX seems often not to update the map files properly. If you installed the package using MiKTeX, Bernard's advice is probably good.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem under Windows with Miktex 2.9. The workaround is pretty simple with Miktex.

1. Launch the Update manager with administrative rights: **Update (Admin)** and follow the instructions to update your distribution.
2. If the "ebgaramond" and/or "ebgaramond-math" packages are not installed, launch the Package Manager with administrative rights: **Package Manager (Admin)** and update the repository entries (Repository->Synchronize). Then install the packages.
3. Launch the Miktex Options manager with administrative rights: **Settings (Admin)** and first hit *Refresh FNDB*, and then *Update Formats*.
4. Restart your LaTeX document editor and compile. Everything should be fine after these steps.